# Digitally sign .xlsx file using System.IO.Packaging in c#

Tags: digital-signature, system.io.packaging

Greeings,

I am trying to digitally sign an excel file using System.IO.Packaging but I can't get this working.

The simplified code I am using is as follows:

```
var packageFile = @"C:\temp\test.xlsx";
var package = Package.Open(packageFile, FileMode.Open);
var packageDigitalSignatureManager = new PackageDigitalSignatureManager(package);
var uriCollection = package.GetParts().ToList().Select(part => part.Uri);
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\certs\adrianganea.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var signature = packageDigitalSignatureManager.Sign(uriCollection, cert);
```

The document appears to be signed but the signature is not valid:
[Invalid Signatures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9cSm.png)

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it seems that the signing certificate needs to be embedded:
`packageDigitalSignatureManager .CertificateOption =CertificateEmbeddingOption.InSignaturePart;`

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging.packagedigitalsignaturemanager.sign?view=netframework-4.8) contains a good example.